# RxJS Pipe does not work in Angular Resolver (but works fine in ngOnInit)

Tags: angular, routes, rxjs, resolver

we tried to add a RxJS pipe in our Angular Resolver: the resolver process starts but doesn't end, so we can't show the result in our html component.

Otherwhise, everything works correctly if we move the pipe on the ngOnInit method of the main component.

What are we doing wrong?

Example with myResolver.ts (**Resolve doesn’t end his process**):

```
resolve(): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {

    let T = mergeMap((user: firebase.User) => {return Observable.fromPromise(user.getIdToken()) });

    let D = mergeMap((token: string) => { return this.http.get('https://myfakedomain.com/user?access_token=' + token) });

    let P = this.afAuth.authState // return Observable<User>

    .pipe(

    T, D

    )

    return P;

    }
```

Example with ngOnInit on mainComponent.ts (**it works!**):

```
ngOnInit() {

    let T = mergeMap((user: firebase.User) => { return Observable.fromPromise(user.getIdToken()) });

    let D = mergeMap((token: string) => {return this.http.get(' https://myfakedomain.com/user?access_token=' + token) });

    let P = this.afAuth.authState // return Observable<User>

    .pipe(

    T, D

    ).subscribe(data => this.myData = data);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306545/resolver-does-not-resolve-if-another-data-stream-is-added), it should be applicable.

It seems that a filtering operator (e.g. first, last, take...) has to be added alongside transformation operator to properly return the result.

Line from the question: `let P = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(T, D)`
should be extended with a filtering operator, e.g.: `let P = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(T, D, first())`.