# Resolver does not resolve if another data stream is added

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-router, angular-resolver

I am trying to use a resolver in order to retrieve data depending on the given parameters the route holds.

Unfortunately, the moment I add another data stream that my data depends on the resolver never actually resolves.

If I directly return an immediately resolving value everything works fine.
I debugged the situation to see that I receive all partial information but it just fails to actually resolve in the end.

Here's a quick sample. Hit me up if there's more code needed to understand the problem.

MyService:

```
export class MyService {
  get(bar) {
    return of(new Foo(bar));
  }
}
```

SecondService (This one retrieves data from the backend):

```
export class SecondService {
  private readonly _observable: Observable<Bar>;
  constructor() {
    this._observable = merge(
      // Other manipulations
    ).pipe(
      // other manipulations
      shareReplay(1)
    )
  }

  observable(): Observable<Bar> {
    return this._observable;
  }
}
```

Resolver:

```
export class MyResolver {
  constructor(_secondService: SecondService, _myService: MyService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Foo> {
    // Does not work - Simply does not resolve
    // return this._secondService
    //   .observable()
    //   .pipe(
    //     switchMap((bar) => this._myService.get(bar)),
    //   );

    // WORKS
    return of(new Foobar('sampleData'));
  }
}
```

Router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'someroute',
    component: SomeComponent,
    canActivate: [SomeGuard],
    resolve: {
      myData: MyResolver,
    },
  },
];
```

Component:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private readonly _route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._route.data
      .subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('received:', data);
      this.myData = data;      
    });
  }
}
```

SomeComponent.html

```
<pre *ngIf="myData">
  Received: {{ myData | json }}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to my problem is rather simple and had nothing to do with subscribing to the resolved observables, as the framework already did that automagically.

In order for a resolver to finish, all the streams it depends on need to `complete`. If you happen to use a hot observable it is required to use another operator like `take` so that the stream completes at that location.

So, all the code remains the same, except that I changed the resolver to:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Foo> {
  return this._secondService
    .observable()
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((bar) => this._myService.get(bar)),
  );
}
```

@eduPeeth: Thank you for your answer/suggestions, unfortunately, it was a far more minor issue.

Comment: Encountered the same issue with resolver. Resolver just hangs until the stream has ended. Similarly, I was using `return this.do().pipe(first());` and it needs either `take`, `first`, or anything that ends the stream before it can resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Observable only get executed when you call `Observable.subscribe()`  explicitly . I don't see anywhere in your code where you are subscribing to your Observables.

Note : Concept of resolve is related to Promise not with Observable.

Try :

```
export class MyResolver {
  constructor(_secondService: SecondService, _myService: MyService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Foo> {
    // Does not work - Simply does not resolve
     return this._secondService
       .observable()
       .pipe(
         take(1),
         switchMap((bar) => this._myService.get(bar)),
       }     
       );

    // WORKS
    return of(new Foobar('sampleData')).pipe(
         take(1),
         switchMap((bar) => this._myService.get(bar)),          
     });
  }
}
```

Subscribe where you need the result.

Comment: That's correct, I am not explicitly calling `.subscribe()` on any of the given observables. I thought this was done _magically_ by angular since the documentation does not state it anywhere (https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter). If anything, I subscribe to the router's data within my target component to retrieve the given data that has been resolved. I added the component in question to my initial post.

Comment: You need to subscribe each and every Observable at some or other place where you  are expecting a value returned from your Observable. Kindly think about your requirement once and try to subscribe. Try to update the code , if you still face issue , help you out.

Comment: I have no idea how I could possibly add your suggestion. How would I `subscribe()` to my custom resolver if angular itself does instantiate the resolver and passes the data further to the component. As described in the question, the data *is* in fact flowing, the resolver just does not resolve in the end.

Comment: Added some code snippet try and see are you getting results or not?

Comment: As described in my own answer, it was a missing `take()` execution that caused the problem. In the end I was subscribing to the resolved Observable within my component already. This is also where I needed the results so subscribing within the resolver would have left me with the same problem again - No data within my component. Anyways, thank you for your time, suggestions and help!